# uploading unity game to playstore I got an error crash with adMob

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

when I try to Upload a new game  I got this Pre_launch error
ack trace

```
******************************************************************************

    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.DefaultCompany.PharaosPinBall, PID: 17316
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

******************************************************************************
* Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here:                          *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to find your app ID.                                                       *
******************************************************************************
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6445)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5987)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5902)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:200)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
******************************************************************************
* Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here:                          *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to find your app ID.                                                       *
******************************************************************************
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.ahg.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@20.4.0:22)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@20.4.0:1)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6440)
    ... 10 more
```

this site "https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest"
put  a solution for java
???

Comment: Your game crashes because you didn't setup admob application id in the AndroidManifest.xml file. Put your application id in the manifest like showing in that link and you'll be good to go.

Comment: thak you Jaimin            this is what i already have in 
 my  AndroidManifest.xml file. so what I add to it? android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="com.aym_awadallah.PharoahsPinBall" />
  </application>

Comment: your admob application id look likes this ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713

Comment: yes I found it (this is my first time using ads) THANK YOU JAIMN  for your help